# FtpWebRequest throws System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in

Tags: c#, .net, ftpwebrequest

I have a windows service that is attempting to create a folder on my FTP server.  The service works fine locally with no issues at all.  When I try and execute on the server however I get a 530.  What's really odd is that I created a little .aspx page that runs the same code and it works.  It only fails in my service code.

```
            var ftpLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpLocation"];
        var ftpUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpUserName"];
        var ftpPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpPassword"];

        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpLocation);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
        request.EnableSsl = true;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);
        try
        {
            logger.Debug("Calling MakeDirectory for " + ftpPath);

            using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != FtpStatusCode.PathnameCreated)
                    throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("FTP failed with the following response: {0} - {1}",
                        response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription));
                response.Close();
            }
            logger.Debug("Calling MakeDirectory for " + ftpPath);

        }
```

I should also note the directory I'm trying to create has a space in it, but again it works 100% correct on my aspx page.

Comment: Looks like your username and password are wrong.

Comment: ugh!  I looked at the password at least a dozen times.  Turns our our deployment server is replacing 3 characters in our password when it deploys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugh! I looked at the password at least a dozen times. Turns our our deployment server is replacing 3 characters in our password when it deploys